# Is $\rho(X_1\dots X_r)^{2/r}\leq \frac{d}{r}\cdot\rho(X_1\otimes X_1+\dots+X_r\otimes X_r)$ for $d\times d$-real matries $X_1,\dots,X_r$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities, tensor-products, spectral-radius

Let $\rho(A)$ denote the spectral radius of a square matrix $A$. Let $r,d$ be positive integers. Let $X_1,\dots,X_r$ be $d\times d$-real matrices. Then do we necessarily have $$\rho(X_1\dots X_r)^{2/r}\leq \frac{d}{r}\cdot\rho(X_1\otimes X_1+\dots+X_r\otimes X_r)?$$

If $X_1,\dots,X_r$ are $d\times d$-real matrices with $d\leq r$ and
$$\rho(X_1\dots X_r)^{2/r}=\frac{d}{r}\cdot\rho(X_1\otimes X_1+\dots+X_r\otimes X_r),$$
then is $\text{rank}(X_j)=1$ for $1\leq j\leq r$?

If $1\leq d\leq r$, then do there always exist $d\times d$-real matrices $X_1,\dots,X_r$ with
$$\rho(X_1\dots X_r)^{2/r}=\frac{d}{r}\cdot\rho(X_1\otimes X_1+\dots+X_r\otimes X_r)?$$

I have used a gradient descent algorithm to try to find counterexamples of this inequality, and the gradient descent algorithm was good at finding examples where
$$\rho(X_1\dots X_r)^{2/r}\approx\frac{d}{r}\cdot\rho(X_1\otimes X_1+\dots+X_r\otimes X_r),$$ but in all these examples, we have $\text{rank}(X_j)=1$ for all $j$, and the gradient descent algorithm was unable to find any cases where $$\rho(X_1\dots X_r)^{2/r}>\frac{d}{r}\cdot\rho(X_1\otimes X_1+\dots+X_r\otimes X_r).$$

Comment: Is $d$ the size of matrices? Is $\rho$ the spectral radius?

Comment: I know that $$\rho(X_1\dots X_r)^{2/r}\leq \rho(X_1\otimes X_1+\dots+X_r\otimes X_r)$$ for all real matrices $X_1,\dots,X_r$. My computer calculations suggest that if $X_1,\dots,X_r$ are $d\times d$ matrices with $$\rho(X_1\dots X_r)^{2/r}=\rho(X_1\otimes X_1+\dots+X_r\otimes X_r)$$ and $d\geq r$, then $\text{Rank}(X_k)\leq r-d+1$ for $k\in\{1,\dots,r\}.$

Comment: If $\mathbf{x}_1,\dots,\mathbf{x}_{r}\in\mathbb{R}^d$ are column vectors, and $P$ is the matrix defined by $$P=\mathbf{x}_1\mathbf{x}_1^T+\dots+\mathbf{x}_r\mathbf{x}_r^T,$$ then $$\|P\|_2^2\geq\frac{1}{\min(r,d)}(\|\mathbf{x}_1\|_2^2+\dots+\|\mathbf{x}_r\|_2^2)^2.$$ Therefore, $$(\|\mathbf{x}_1\|\dots\|\mathbf{x}_r\|)^{4/r}\leq[\frac{1}{r}(\|\mathbf{x}_1\|^2+\dots\|\mathbf{x}_r\|^2)]^{2}\leq \frac{\min(r,d)}{r^2}\cdot\|P\|_{2}^{2}.$$ Here $\|A\|_2$ denotes the Frobenius norm of $A$.

Comment: Rewriting the above inequality by replacing $\mathbf{x}_1,\dots,\mathbf{x}_r$ with matrices, we get $$(\|A_1\|_2\dots\|A_r\|_2)^{4/r}\leq\frac{\min(r,d^2)}{r^2}\|A_1\otimes A_1+\dots+ A_r\otimes A_r\|_2^2$$ for real matrices $A_1,\dots,A_r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to all these questions is **Yes**. We shall answer this question in the more general case when $X_1,\dots,X_r$ are complex matrices (the inequality for this question looks a little bit different in the complex case since we need to apply conjugations and transposes). This answer shall be in the context of quantum channels. I recommend [The Theory of Quantum Information](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/TQI/) by John Watrous (2018) for more information on quantum information theory. Much of content of this answer is similar to the answers to [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/423510/22277); fedja remarked that the idea behind the answer to that previous question also applies to this question, so fedja could have answered at least most of this question before I did.

A function $\mathcal{E}:M_d(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_d(\mathbb{C})$ is said to be positive if $\mathcal{E}(P)$ is positive semidefinite whenever $P$ is positive semidefinite. If $W$ is a finite dimensional vector space, then let $L(W)$ be the set of all homomorphisms from $W$ to $W$. We say that $\mathcal{E}:M_d(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_d(\mathbb{C})$ is completely positive if whenever $V$ is a finite dimensional complex Hilbert space, the mapping $\mathcal{E}\otimes 1_V:L(\mathbb{C}^d\otimes V)\rightarrow L(\mathbb{C}^d\otimes V)$ is positive. We say that a linear mapping $\mathcal{E}:M_d(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_d(\mathbb{C})$ is trace preserving if $\text{Tr}(\mathcal{E}(A))=\text{Tr}(A)$ whenever $A\in M_d(\mathbb{C})$. We say that a linear mapping $\mathcal{E}:M_d(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_d(\mathbb{C})$ is a quantum channel if it is both completely positive and trace preserving.

If $X_1,\dots,X_r$ are complex matrices, then define a mapping $\Phi(X_1,\dots,X_r):M_{d}(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_{d}(\mathbb{C})$ by letting
$$\Phi(X_1,\dots,X_r)(X)=X_1XX_1^*+\dots+X_rXX_r^*.$$ The completely positive mappings from $M_d(\mathbb{C})$ to $M_d(\mathbb{C})$ are precisely the mappings of the form
$\Phi(X_1,\dots,X_r)$, and the quantum channels $\mathcal{E}:M_d(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_d(\mathbb{C})$ are precisely the mappings of the form $\Phi(X_1,\dots,X_r)$ where $X_1^*X_1+\dots+X_r^*X_r=1_d$.

If $\mathcal{E}$ is a quantum channel, then $\rho(\mathcal{E})=1$; quantum channels are a lot like stochastic matrices.

I claim that $\rho(X_1\dots X_r)^{2/r}\leq\frac{d}{r}\rho(\Phi(X_1,\dots,X_r))$ whenever $X_1,\dots,X_r$ are $d\times d$-complex matrices.

Let $O_{d,r}$ be the set of all $(X_1,\dots,X_r)\in M_d(\mathbb{C})^r$ such that
$\Phi(X_1,\dots,X_r)$ is not nilpotent. Let $E_{d,r}$ be the set of all $(X_1,\dots,X_r)\in M_d(\mathbb{C})^r$ such that
$\Phi(\lambda BX_1B^{-1},\dots,\lambda BX_rB^{-1})$ is a quantum channel for some complex $\lambda\neq 0$ and invertible matrix $B$. Then by [my answer to my other question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/423803/22277), $E_{d,r}$ is a dense subset of $O_{d,r}$, and clearly $O_{d,r}$ is dense in $M_d(\mathbb{C})^r$.

Observe that $$\frac{\rho(Y_1\dots Y_r)^{2/r}}{\rho(\Phi(Y_1,\dots,Y_r))}=\frac{\rho(\lambda BY_1B^{-1}\dots \lambda BY_rB^{-1})^{2/r}}{\rho(\Phi(\lambda BY_1B^{-1},\dots,\lambda BY_rB^{-1}))}$$ whenever $\lambda\neq 0$, $B$ is invertible, and $\Phi(Y_1,\dots,Y_r)$ is not nilpotent. Therefore, if $\rho(Z_1\dots Z_r)^{2/r}\leq\frac{d}{r}\rho(\Phi(Z_1,\dots,Z_r))$ whenever $\Phi(Z_1,\dots,Z_r)$ is a quantum channel, then $\rho(Y_1\dots Y_r)^{2/r}\leq\frac{d}{r}\rho(\Phi(Y_1,\dots,Y_r))$ whenever $(Y_1,\dots,Y_r)\in E_{d,r},$
so because $E_{d,r}$ is dense in $M_{d}(\mathbb{C})^{r}$, we will be able to conclude that $\rho(X_1\dots X_r)^{2/r}\leq\frac{d}{r}\rho(\Phi(X_1,\dots,X_r))$ whenever $X_1,\dots,X_r\in M_d(\mathbb{C})^r$.

If $\Phi(Z_1,\dots,Z_r)$ is a quantum channel, then $$d=\text{Tr}(1_d)=\text{Tr}(Z_1^*Z_1+\dots+Z_r^*Z_r)=\|Z_1\|^2_2+\dots+\|Z_r\|_2^2$$ where $\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes the Frobenius norm.

Therefore, by the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality, we have our main inequality, namely

$$\rho(Z_1\dots Z_r)^{2/r}\leq\|Z_1\dots Z_r\|_\infty^{2/r}\leq(\|Z_1\|_\infty^2\dots\|Z_r\|_\infty^2)^{1/r}\leq(\|Z_1\|_2^2\dots\|Z_r\|_2^2)^{1/r}\leq\frac{\|Z_{1}\|_2^2+\dots+\|Z_r\|_2^2}{r}
=\frac{d}{r}=\frac{d}{r}\rho(\Phi(Z_1,\dots,Z_r)).$$

Furthermore, if $\rho(Z_1\dots Z_r)^{2/r}=\frac{d}{r}\rho(\Phi(Z_1,\dots,Z_r))$,
then $\|Z_j\|_\infty^2=\|Z_j\|^2_2=d/r$ for all $j$. However, The only way to get $\|Z_{j}\|_\infty=\|Z_j\|_2$ is if $\text{Rank}(Z_j)=1$ since $\|W\|_{\infty}=\|W\|_2$ precisely when $\text{Rank}(W)=1$.

Therefore, for all $j$, there are column vectors $u_j,v_j$ such that $Z_j=u_jv_j^*$.

In this case, $$\|Z_j\|_2^2=\text{Tr}((u_jv_j^*)(u_jv_j^*)^*)=\text{Tr}(u_jv_j^*v_ju_j^*)=
\text{Tr}(u_j^*u_jv_j^*v_j)=\|u_j\|^2\cdot\|v_j\|^2.$$ Therefore, $\|Z_j\|_2=\|u_j\|\cdot\|v_j\|=\sqrt{d/r}$.

$$\rho(Z_1\dots Z_r)=|\text{Tr}(Z_1\dots Z_r)|=|\text{Tr}(u_1v_1^*\dots u_rv_r^*)|
=|\text{Tr}(v_1^*u_2\dots v_r^*u_1)|$$
$$=|\langle v_1,u_2\rangle|\dots|\langle v_r,u_1\rangle|.$$

Since $\rho(Z_1\dots Z_r)=\|Z_1\|_\infty\dots\|Z_r\|_\infty$, we have
$$|\langle v_1,u_2\rangle|\dots|\langle v_r,u_1\rangle|=\|u_1\|\cdot\|v_1\|\dots \|u_r\|\cdot\|v_r\|.$$
This means that there are constants $\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_r$ where
$v_j=\overline{\gamma_j}\cdot u_{j+1}$. Therefore,
$Z_j=u_jv_j^*=u_j\gamma_j u_{j+1}^*=\gamma_j u_ju_{j+1}^*$.

Now, set $w_j=\|u_j\|\cdot v_{j}=\|u_j\|\cdot\overline{\gamma_j}u_{j+1}.$

Then $$1_d=\sum_{j=1}^{r}Z_j^*Z_j=\sum_{j=1}^{r}(u_jv_j^*)^*u_jv_j^*=\sum_{j=1}^{r}v_ju_j^*u_jv_j^*=\sum_{j=1}^{r}\|u_{j}\|^2\cdot v_jv_j^*=\sum_{j=1}^{r}w_jw_j^*.$$

Observe that $1_d=\sum_{j=1}^{r}w_jw_j^*$ precisely when $x=\sum_{j=1}^{r}w_{j}\cdot\langle x,w_j\rangle$. We say that a tuple of vectors $(h_1,\dots,h_r)$ is a normalized tight frame if $1_d=\sum_{j=1}^{r}h_jh_j^*$. We say that a normalized tight frame is equal-norm if $\|h_1\|=\dots=\|h_r\|$. Observe that $\|w_j\|^2=d/r$ for all $j$, so $(w_1,\dots,w_r)$ is an equal-norm tight frame.

One can also obtain tuples $(Z_1,\dots,Z_r)$ where $\Phi(Z_1,\dots,Z_r)$ is a quantum channel and where $\rho(Z_1,\dots,Z_r)^{2/r}=d/r$ from equal-norm tight frames. Suppose that $(w_1,\dots,w_r)\in(\mathbb{C}^d)^r$ is an equal-norm tight frame. Then we necessarily have $\|w_j\|^2_2=d/r$ for all $j$. Now, suppose that $|\alpha_j\beta_j|^2=r/d$ for $1\leq j\leq r$. Let $v_j=\alpha_jw_j,u_{j+1}=\beta_{j+1}w_j$, and as always, set $Z_j=u_jv_j^*$ for $1\leq j\leq r$. Then the reader can verify that $\Phi(Z_1,\dots,Z_r)$ is a quantum channel with $\rho(Z_1,\dots,Z_r)^{2/r}=\frac{d}{r}$ and every quantum channel $\Phi(Z_1,\dots,Z_r)$ with $\rho(Z_1,\dots,Z_r)^{2/r}=\frac{d}{r}$ is of this form.

The existence of equal-norm tight frames $(w_1,\dots,w_r)\in(\mathbb{R}^d)^r$ is already a known result. For example, the existence of such frames is Corollary 7.1 in [An Introduction to Finite Tight Frames](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/%7Ewaldron/Preprints/Frame-book/draft26-7.17.pdf) by Shayne F. D. Waldron.

By applying continuity, we can actually show that $\text{Rank}(X_j)=1$ even if we drop the assumption that $\Phi(X_1,\dots,X_r)$ is a quantum channel.

Let $f:O_{d,r}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the function where
$f(X_1,\dots,X_r)=\frac{\rho(X_1\dots X_r)^{2/r}}{\rho(\Phi(X_1,\dots,X_r))}.$

Let $g^-:M_d(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the function where
$g^-(X)=|\lambda_1\lambda_2|$ where $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_d$ are the eigenvalues of $X$ arranged in an order so that $|\lambda_1|\geq|\lambda_2|\geq\dots\geq|\lambda_d|$.

Define $g:O_{d,r}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by letting $$g(X_1,\dots,X_r)=\frac{g^-(X_1)+\dots+g^-(X_r)}{r\cdot\rho(\Phi(X_1,\dots,X_r))}.$$

Suppose that $(X_1,\dots,X_r)\in O_{d,r}$ and $f(X_1,\dots,X_r)=\frac{d}{r}$. Then for each $\delta>0$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $(X_1,\dots,X_r)$ where if
$(Y_1,\dots,Y_r)\in U$, then $f(Y_1,\dots,Y_r)>\frac{d}{r}-\delta$. Now, let $(Y_1,\dots,Y_r)\in U\cap E_{d,r}$. Then there is some $\lambda$ and invertible $B$ where if we set $Z_j=\lambda BY_jB^{-1}$ for all $j$, then $\Phi(Z_1,\dots,Z_r)$ is a quantum channel. Now, let $\lambda_{j,1},\dots,\lambda_{j,d}$ be the eigenvalues of $Z_j$ ordered in a way so that $|\lambda_{j,1}|\geq|\lambda_{j,2}|\geq\dots\geq|\lambda_{j,d}|$. Let $\sigma_{j,1}\geq\dots\geq\sigma_{j,d}$ denote the singular values of $Z_j$.

Then
$$\frac{d}{r}-\delta<f(Y_1,\dots,Y_r)=f(Z_1,\dots,Z_r)=\rho(Z_1\dots Z_r)^{2/r}
\leq(\sigma_{1,1}^2\dots\sigma_{r,1}^2)^{1/r}$$
$$\leq\frac{\sigma_{1,1}^2+\dots+\sigma_{r,1}^2}{r}
\leq\frac{(\sigma_{1,1}^2+\sigma_{1,2}^2)+\dots+(\sigma_{r,1}^2+\sigma_{r,2}^2)}{r}$$
$$\leq\frac{\|Z_1\|_2^2+\dots+\|Z_r\|_2^2}{r}=\frac{d}{r}.$$

We conclude that $\sigma_{j,1}^2\leq\frac{d}{r}$ and $\sigma_{j,2}^2\leq\delta$. Therefore, by Weyl's inequality, we have
$$|\lambda_{j,1}\lambda_{j,2}|\leq\sigma_{i,1}\sigma_{j,2}\leq\sqrt{\frac{d\delta}{r}}.$$

Therefore, we have
$$g(Y_1,\dots,Y_r)=g(Z_1,\dots,Z_r)\leq\sqrt{\frac{d\delta}{r}}.$$

We therefore conclude that $g(X_1,\dots,X_r)=0$ which means that
$\text{Rank}(X_j)\leq 1$ for $1\leq j\leq r$.